# extra has_many requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Assignment: title:string
Permission: user_id:integer, subject_class:string, subject_id:integer, action:string

Assignment has_many :permissions, :foreign_key => :subject_id
But how do I make sure that it knows about the subject_class == self.class.to_s requirement?

Update: Using :conditions => {:subject_class => 'Assignment'}, how can I ensure when I do permissions.new the :subject_class is also set.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you want to use polymorphic associations for (http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/db-relationships/polymorphic)

In your Assignment model, you would do the following:

```
has_many :permissions, :as => :subject
```

And in your Permission model, you would do this:

```
belongs_to :subject, :polymorphic => true
```

However, you'll need to rename the subject_class field to subject_type in order for this to work implicitly. When all of this is done, you'll have everything you asked for for free from Rails. You won't need to pass :subject_type when you create a new Permission. You can create a Permission like this and :subject_type will be filled automatically for you:

```
assignment = Assignment.create(:title => "My Assignment")
permission = Permission.create(:subject => assignment, :action => "read", :user => current_user)

- or -

assignment.permission.create(:user => current_user, :action => "read")
```